# Execute a function on error php

Tags: php

Once i initiated a function i am setting a flag on DB to `TRUE`.

and i need to set it `FALSE` on the end of the function.

Ex:

```
Class Preprocessor extends Machine{

  function process(){
    $this->db->setValue(TRUE); //Setting DB flag to TRUE

    //OTHER CODES

     $this->close_db_value(); // Setting DB flag to FALSE

  }

  function close_db_value(){
    $this->db->setValue(FALSE); //Setting DB flag to FALSE
  }

}
```

As you can see that it will work in normal cases, But if some error encountered in //OTHER CODES section then it will not execute the rest of codes.

The function mainly work in background (But not as a command line,its just closing the connection and start executing on background).

How can i ensure that the `close_db_value()` function executed upon script termination ?

Some of possibilities

1. Some critical errors that which leads the script to termination
2. `exit` called somewhere on the //OTHER CODE section
3. PHP `max_execution_time` exceeded
4. A Force Kill

Please help.

Comment: A `try { ... } finally { ... }` block should always execute the finally block, no matter if there was a fatal error or not. I have no idea if it will execute in the latter three cases though. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: @Sumurai8 Its not, The last one is the problematic one. The fact is that the script may run about 1 Hour on background and my hosting provider dont like this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function in PHP.  Place the name of the callback function you want called in case of error as the first parameter.  Put the level of error (optional) that you want as the trigger as the second parameter.

If you are looking to handle every other type of error (except SIGKILLs or force quits), you can also try using [register_shutdown_function()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) with a [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) and a switch-case statement with the various types of errors you wish to handle (E_NOTICE, E_DEPRECATED, etc.).

For example,

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdown_callback');

function shutdown_callback(){
    $error_type = error_get_last();
    switch($error_type){
        case E_ERROR: break;
        case E_WARNING: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.`

Comment: @Red I just modified my answer to also add an alternative way, after doing some light research.  Also, `register_shutdown_function()`'s documentation specifies how to handle a SIGTERM/SIGKILL if you need that handled as well, but I've never bothered with that.

Comment: Thanks, But in fact i can handle the first 2 listed possible terminations `register_shutdown_function()` will fail if the timeout is exceeded.Is there any system (OS) level solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The `__destruct();` magic function will also execute every time the script ends, or an object is unloaded.